# How to proxy an image with Node JS and Multer?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I send an image in form-data using [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK3d9.png) to my server (1 request).
Right after that I have to send this image in the request just like that to 3rd party service but with api keys in headers (2 request).
When I get the response from the 2 request I need to send it back to 1 request.
So the question is:

How can I take an image from the 1 request and put it into 2 request? I do not need to store it on my server, I just need to proxy it to a 3rd party service.
I found out that the Multer might help me, but it returns [a strange looking object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0FHK.png) from 1 request's file and I don't know what to do with this one

Answer (score 0):

You should use [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)(option to temp store file) and get the file data i.e get all the files from it. Then, create a formData object using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data). Finally, you can add data to the form object and set headers and send data to any API.

```
npm i express-fileupload --save 
npm i form-data --save
```

In your project

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const FormData = require('form-data')

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', async (request, response, next) => {
  const { files } = request

  const formData = new FormData()

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i]

    formData.append('files', file)
  }
  const formHeaders = formData.getHeaders(); // based on the need
  
  // now you can send the form data to any end-point
  // you can use axios to do that or any other lib

})
```

Comment: express-fileupload sounds like a really good idea, but now I got stuck in 'source.on is not a function' error returned by form-data, and even google can't help me. 
Also I found out that arrays are not (already?) in use in express-fileupload, but I still could get my image using files.file, so it's not the problem.

Comment: Can you add more details here about the error?

Comment: I get an object from req.files.file ('file' is the name of field in form-data I send from Postman). 
`{
  name: 'Screenshot 2021-04-19 at 12.24.18.png',
  data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 0b 40 00 00 07 08 08 06 00 00 00 af e4 40 15 00 00 0c 6a 69 43 43 50 49 43 43 20 50 72 6f 66 69 ... 425394 more bytes>,
  size: 425444,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  md5: 'af4a946774a56e6debc661ae2c1d9938',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}`
When I try to data.append('file', file) I get this error

Comment: Google says smth like 'Form-data can only take types like String, Buffer..' and etc, but I doesn't really help me :)